# My recursive function in laravel does not call itself

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-blade

I am writing a recursive function to call the child record from the parent record. It seems not to be working. i am getting this error; "Trying to get property 'refid' of non-object". Where am i getting it wrong. Please any idea? below is the code Snippet.

**the function controller**

```php
public function DisplayDetail($id)
{
    $displayDetail = DB::table('tblmembers')
        ->where('refid',$id)
        ->get();
    return $this->DisplayDetail($displayDetail->refid);
}
```

**main controller where the function is called**

```php
public function dashboard()
{ 

    $profile = DB::table('tblmembers')->where('username',$userid)->first();
    $data['userdetail'] = $this->DisplayDetail($profile->memid); 
    return view('main.userArea',$data);  
}
```

**the blade where the record fetched is displayed**

```php
@foreach($userdetail as $userd)
    {{ $userd->memid }}
@endforeach
```

my sample data

```
refid   |   memid
-------------------
12345   |  123456
123456  |  1234567
123456  |  1234568
123456  |  1234569
1234567 |  1234570
```

from the above table; refid: 123456 brought memid: 1234567,1234568,1234569. then refid: 1234567 brought memid: 12345670

i want to display all the memid after login in as a user with memid 123456

Comment: two things fist put some condition when to stop because that's where  you are getting error at last point of your tree you don' have any refid so give you error  
second what you want to return from this function ?

Comment: i have tried it but not working

Comment: what you want to return from this function ?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing one thing wrong in your function `DisplayDetail`. Here the the correction in your function

If you want to get single item then here is the correct code.

```
public function displayDetail($id)
{
    $displayDetail = DB::table('tblmembers')
                       ->where('refid',$id)
                       ->first();
    if($displayDetail) {
         $displayDetail['userdetail'] = $this->displayDetail($displayDetail->refid);
    }
    return $displayDetail;
}
```

And **dashboard** function will be look like this

```
public function dashboard()
{ 
    $profile=DB::table('tblmembers')->where('username',$userid)->first();
    $userDetail = $this->DisplayDetail($profile->memid); 
    return view('main.userArea',[
        'userdetail' => $userDetail
    ]);
}
```

This is the correct code. Try this and let me know if you have another query on this.

Comment: it does not return anything. Its just showing blank page

Comment: Try to debug in `displayDetail` function.. logic is correct. just you need to check your data for which `id` you are querying.

Comment: The error is at this line of code: ' $displayDetail['userdetail'] = $this->DisplayDetail($displayDetail->refid);'. it does not seems to return anything

Comment: can you provide some sample of response data. So I can get an idea of your implementation.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong.. because for function `DisplayDetail` first time you are passing `memid` but in recursive you are passing `refid`. I think you have to pass same id in both cases either `memid` or `refid`. please correct if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> Trying to get property 'refid' of non-object

is occuring because your database query is using `->get()`, which returns a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-collections), rather than an object. You cannot get the property `->refid` on a Collection, you can only get it from an object that resides in the collection.

As Lakhwinder Singh shows in his code, you need to use `->first()`, as this will return one object. I would suggest using `->firstOrFail()`, that way you will either get back an object which matches your ID, or it will fail if it cannot find it.

If you do:

```
$displayDetail = DB::table('tblmembers')
        ->where('refid',$id)
        ->firstOrFail();
```

You will now be able to call:

`$displayDetail->refid`

You can use that in your function call to `displayDetail`.

Comment: i have use firstOrFail() but not working. am getting this error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::firstOrFail(). Meanwhile, how do i display the information using get() because that is what i want to achieve by looping through the child tree. thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
    public function DisplayDetail($id,$data=[])
    {

     $displayDetail = DB::table('tblmembers')
            ->where('refid',$id)
            ->get();
    if($displayDetail && isset($displayDetail->refid))// your condition for last child 
    {   
     $data = $this->DisplayDetail($displayDetail->refid,$data);
    }
     $data[] = array('refid' =>$displayDetail->id ,
                     'memid' => $displayDetail->secondid );
    return $data;
    }
```

i'll explain you later first modify according to your requirement and run

Comment: am getting errorTrying to get property 'refid' of non-object at  ' $data[] = array('refid' =>$displayDetail->id ,
                     'memid' => $displayDetail->secondid );'

Comment: print_r with echo"<br> " your displayDetail it might return you array .  or might be empty